# How do i read a .txt file into R with different separators, and run on lines?

Tags: r, dataframe, text, read.table

I have a large .txt file in the below format showing date, user and product reviews for a large number of users;

```
    YYYY:MM:D1 @Username1: this is a product review
    YYYY:MM:D1 @Username2: this is also a product review
    YYYY:MM:D1 @Username3: this is also a product review that
    runs to the next line
    YYYY:MM:D1 @Username4: this here is also a product review
```

I want to extract this to a dataframe with 3 columns, like so:

```
    date/time      username      comment
    yyyy/mm/dd     @Username1    this is a product review   
    yyyy/mm/dd     @Username2    this is also a product review   
    yyyy/mm/dd     @Username3    this is also a product review contained in the same row
    yyyy/mm/dd     @Username4    this here is also a product review
```

Using the standard R base command

```
    read.table("filename.txt", fill=TRUE)
```

gives me a dataframe which treats each word in the product review as a different column. It also turns the reviews long enough to be 'run-on lines' into new rows, i.e.

```
    V1          V2          V3          V4          V5          
    yy/mm/dd    Username1   this        is          a 
    product     review 
    ...
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is the whitespace between columns just a space character (which is dumb)? If so, you can only import without separators (i.e., as one column) and `strsplit` with a regex afterwards.

Comment: In the package `tidyr` there's also `separate_rows()` for exactly the string splitting, which @Roland describes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this in a few different ways. One approach would be to import the data into a single column and then use `tidyr::separate` or `data.table::strsplit` to [split the column at the appropriate places](http://www.modernstatisticswithr.com/messychapter.html#splittingcolumns). Here's an example with `tidyr`:

```
# Use a separator symbol that is unlikely to appear in the file,
# to read the data into a single column:
data <- read.table("filename.txt", sep = "^")

# First split the column at the @-sign, and then at the ": "-part:
library(tidyr)
data %>% separate(V1,
                into = c("Date", "User"),
                sep = " @") %>%
    separate(User,
        into = c("User", "Review"),
        sep = ": ") -> data

# If you want to add back the @-sign to the usernames:
data$User <- paste("@", data$User, sep = "")
```

Comment: Thank you @MansT! works beautifully and clear explanation

Comment: i have upvoted the answer, it just doesn't appear bc i'm a new user